# Fuller/Dymaxion in proj4/gdal/qgis?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, c++, proj, c

I know this question has been asked a million times already, but I can't find many detailed responses on exactly what I want to do.

As far as I can tell, the full C code for the fuller projection is available here: http://www.rwgrayprojects.com/rbfnotes/maps/graymap6.html

Since I'm not using it for any commercial purposes (personal use only) it doesn't violate the licensing. It would appear as though it would only need a few changes (if any) to incorporate into proj4. My only question is, how do I incorporate it into proj4 and have it recognized by gdal? Is it as simple as putting the ported, proj4 compatible version into a PJ_Fuller.c file and building the project? How would I assign it my own custom ESPG code, and once proj4 is rebuilt, would I just symlink my custom branch of it so that QGIS looks there and sees it? Or would I also have to rewrite the proj4 file in c++ for gdal?

I'm running Debian if that makes any difference.

Comment: For use in GDAL, you would need code for the inverse projection. From the link I can't see if there are formulas for that. For integration into PROJ.4, you better ask on the mailing list. The real developers are reading there, not here.

Comment: @andrej I'd like to not get the devs of proj4 involved in this, as that would most certainly get into some sort of legal licensing issues with the fuller institute. Proj4 has already clearly stated that they will not get it Incorporated in a bug ticket I saw earlier when researching this.

Comment: You should double-check the licensing issues. When the Fuller Institute wanted Esri to implement Fuller (can't call it Dymaxion), I believe our legal department asked them to make it public domain. We weren't interested in a license just for us.That doesn't mean you can get our inverse though!

Comment: @AlexMcVittie you can make a fork of PROJ.4 just for your own use. By studying the implementation of similar projections you might get a clue how to add a new one. But that still does not solve the inverse function you need in GDAL.

Comment: Turns out that if you project your shapefiles and other data in ArcMap to Fuller, QGIS can read the .prj file correctly and display the geographic data properly! Luckily I have access to ArcMap, so that solves this issue for me.

Comment: Update from my earlier comment. While we did ask BFI to put the Fuller projection into the public domain, they didn't, but I don't have access to exactly what the agreement was.

Comment: How about the Uber H3 system then: they break up the Fuller projection further into hexagons and pentagons, such that the pentagons are out in the oceans.  And their code is open source.  https://observablehq.com/@fil/h3-oddities  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310555/using-uber-h3-hexagon-grids-in-qgis